# NginX SSL Offload $scheme has no effect

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I'm trying to do ssh offload with Nginx and Tomcat. My setup is:
browser -(HTTPS)-> nginx -> (http/https) -> tomcat

I have setup nginx to forward the request scheme in x-forwarded-proto header.

```
                    proxy_pass http://default_upstream;
                    add_header Set-Cookie "SRVGROUP=$group; path=/";
                    proxy_next_upstream error;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-URI $uri;
                    proxy_set_header X-ARGS $args;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header Refer $http_refer;
                    proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
                    proxy_set_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200";
```

On tomcat I print the X-Forwarded-Proto header I always get http. 
If I replace

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

with

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

it all works. But I want to use $scheme as not all of my pages are served over https.

Looking for solutions, or if anyone has had the same problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. In my nginx configuration for ssl someone had left this:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
```

which pretty much redirects to nginx again but on port 80. I commented it out and now it all works fine.

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

method1:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
```

method2:

```
nginx.conf
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;

server.xml:

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
       remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
       remoteIpProxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
       protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto"
       httpsServerPort="443"
    />
```

if you still have problem, I suggest you tcpdump the data between nginx and tomcat

Answer (score 0):

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; is correct for SSL offload. What you seem to be expecting is Nginx to proxy the http connections. That is doable as well, but you need to set that up separately as a listener for port 80, then proxy connections to the upstream server(s).

Basically, you need separate server config blocks for port 443 and port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your config in my devbox with some minor changes. My upstream script sees 'https' when it's accessed from https and sees 'http' when it's from http. So your config works.

The only line I changed is the Host header sent to the upstream. From

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

to

```
proxy_set_header Host my_upstream_domain_name;
```

I have both sites (upstream/downstream) hosted on the same devbox. So my test won't work if the host header is pointing to the current domain name, not the upstream's domain name.

The above change may not be relevant to your test if your upstream is hosted on a different server.